# SwiftUI image picker, url image from camera

Tags: ios, swift, url, swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller

on my SwiftUI project I need to use the url of the image to be reused in other part of the project.

I have created this image picker that allow me to choose between phone album or take a new photo with the iPhone camera (with the var shootNew: Bool)

I facing the following issue: when I use the picker to select the image from the photo album im getting the url of the image, but when I want to take a new picture with the camera I can't get the url of the new picture,

How can I get url of the picture taken with camera?

here my imagePicker

```
struct ImagePickerNew: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var shootNew: Bool
    var needEdit: Bool
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var imageUrl : URL?
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        
        var shootNew: Bool
        var needEdit: Bool
        @Binding var image: UIImage?
        @Binding var isPresented: Bool
        @Binding var imageUrl : URL?
        init(shootNew: Bool, needEdit: Bool, image: Binding<UIImage?>, isPresented:Binding<Bool>, imageURL1 : Binding<URL?>) {
            self.shootNew = shootNew
            self.needEdit = needEdit
            _image = image
            _isPresented = isPresented
            _imageUrl = imageURL1
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let imageEdited = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                self.image = imageEdited
                
            } else {
                self.image = (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage)
            }
            if let imageURLEdited = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL{
                self.imageUrl = imageURLEdited
                debugPrint("ho url")
            } else {
                debugPrint("UNABLE URL")
            }
            self.isPresented = false
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            self.isPresented = false
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(shootNew: shootNew, needEdit: needEdit, image: $image, isPresented: $isPresented, imageURL1: $imageUrl)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerNew>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.navigationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = shootNew ? .camera : .photoLibrary
        picker.allowsEditing = needEdit
        picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage] as [String]
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerNew>) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 4):

you can't get the URL of the photo taken by the camera because it is not written to the disk yet, you should write the photo data to the temporary documents folder first and then get the URL. Here is an example:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
    var selectedImage: UIImage!
    var imageUrl: URL!
    
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = image
    } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = image
    }
    
    if picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera {
        
        let imgName = "\(UUID().uuidString).jpeg"
        let documentDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let localPath = documentDirectory.appending(imgName)
        
        let data = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3)! as NSData
        data.write(toFile: localPath, atomically: true)
        imageUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath)
    } else if let selectedImageUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL {
        imageUrl = selectedImageUrl
    }
    self.mainImageView.image = selectedImage

    MediaAPI.uploadMedia(fileUrl: imageUrl)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```